# error "setting cgroup config for procHooks process: bpf_prog_query(BPF_CGROUP_DEVICE)" on debian 11

Tags: debian, docker

I'm trying to get docker running on Debian 11 (bullseye), but I am currently failing whenever I try to start a container with the following error:

```bash
~$ docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task:
OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process:
error during container init: error setting cgroup config for procHooks process: 
bpf_prog_query(BPF_CGROUP_DEVICE) failed: function not implemented: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:
```

I've read tons of articles and issues about how this error can be fixed by setting up the kernel option `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0` in the bootloader of a given Linux distro. In the case of debian, that is setting up `/etc/default/grub` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"` as shown below:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
```

(same with systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=yes)

then running `update-grub` (I've tried with and without sudo), and finally rebooting the system to initiate the kernel with the said setting.

This doesn't work for me. I'm not sure that Grub is picking the setting. Some articles state that the applied setting can be verified by looking at `/proc/cmdline` but I don't see it:

```bash
cat /proc/cmdline
console=ttymxc2,115200 earlycon=ec_imx6q,0x30880000,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk2p2 rootwait rw
```

Here is some context information of my system:

```bash
~$ uname -a
Linux ucm-imx8m-mini 5.10.35-ucm-imx8m-mini-2.2.1+gbe9842c742e1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 30 13:25:38 UTC 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux

~$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: ucm-imx8m-mini
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: 2b579254d31541d0b6b10e4f33c273de
           Boot ID: fd96317ebda848bb9908c071348a867e
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
            Kernel: Linux 5.10.35-ucm-imx8m-mini-2.2.1+gbe9842c742e1
      Architecture: arm64

~$ docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    24.0.7
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.21.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 7
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 7
 Images: 2
 Server Version: 24.0.7
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: d8f198a4ed8892c764191ef7b3b06d8a2eeb5c7f
 runc version: v1.1.10-0-g18a0cb0
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.10.35-ucm-imx8m-mini-2.2.1+gbe9842c742e1
 Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 1.902GiB
 Name: ucm-imx8m-mini
 ID: 822ea2f7-5cb0-4b3b-8f06-9ebdb1517bae
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Comment: Your kernel is not even a Debian kernel. How can you be sure that Docker's upstream prerequisites are met then?

Comment: 5.10.35-ucm-imx8m-mini-2.2.1+gbe9842c742e1 <-- Not Debian

Comment: ref: https://mediawiki.compulab.com/w/index.php?title=UCM-iMX8M-Mini_NXP_iMX8M-Mini_Debian_Linux . Maybe rebuilding the vendor's kernel with options expected to be present (cgroup, missing netfilter options etc...) by following the link about building. I'd rather pick a board with upstream kernel support rather than vendor-only.

Comment: On an actual Debian-provided kernel, this command: `grep -c BPF /boot/config-5.10*` will return 20 per kernel config file. On your case I suspect less, and in particular missing `CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y` (ie: `grep CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF /boot/config-5.10*` won't find it).

Comment: Doesn't look like a debian kernel, i've not realized that. I'll check into the rebuilding and see if it works.